# Pivot [Transform] a table by days of a month by a specific month & user

Tags: sql, sql-server, pivot, transform

I've two tables named as Records and Users. The table design is like below.

### Table [Records]

**Id, Username, IP, Date**
1, murat, 192.168.1.100, 2019-02-17 04:12:20.470
2, murat, 192.168.1.100, 2019-02-17 04:33:36.120
3, michael, 192.168.120.175, 2019-02-17 08:08:22.210

### Users [Users]

**Username, Name, Mail, Department, Record, Function, Level, Manager, ManagerTop**
murat, Murat, murat@asd.com, 11111, IT, Software Department, 1, Kobe, Michael
michael, Michael, michael@asd.com, 22222, IT, Helpdesk, 2, Shaq, Michael

What I'd like to do is, pivot the table of [Records] by days of a month by specific month and username.

### What I want is something like this:

**Username, Name, ManagerTop, Manager, Month, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30, 31**
murat, Murat, Michael, Kobe, February, No, No, No, No, No, No, No, No, No, No, No, No, No, No, No, No, **Yes**, No, No, No, No, No, No, No, No, No, No, No, No, No, No

I appreciate for your support

Comment: Your readers would appreciate it if you format your code and data so that it is readable.  Format a line as code by adding four or more spaces to that line.

Comment: Could you show us what attempt(s) you've made to achiy your goal, and/or the research you completed to try to achieve it? If you did perform research, what was it you didn't understand? Perhaps we can help explain the parts you were having trouble with.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A `PIVOT` can indeed be used for this.

And the "Users" table can be joined to the pivot.

```
SELECT 
pvt.Username, 
usr.Name,
usr.ManagerTop, 
usr.Manager,
pvt.[Month], 
IIF([1]>0,'Yes','No') AS [1],
IIF([2]>0,'Yes','No') AS [2],
-- Add the other days
IIF([17]>0,'Yes','No') AS [17],
-- Add the other days
IIF([30]>0,'Yes','No') AS [30],
IIF([31]>0,'Yes','No') AS [31]
FROM
(
   SELECT
   rec.Username,  
   YEAR(rec.[Date]) AS [Year],
   DATENAME(month, rec.[Date]) AS [Month],
   DAY(rec.[Date]) AS [Day]
   FROM [Records] rec
   WHERE rec.[Date] >= DATEFROMPARTS(YEAR(GetDate()), 1, 1)
) src
PIVOT 
(
  COUNT([Day])
  FOR [Day] IN (
     [1],[2],[3],[4],[5],[6],[7],[8],
     [9],[10],[11],[12],[13],[14],[15],[16],
     [17],[18],[19],[20],[21],[22],[23],[24],
     [25],[26],[27],[28],[29],[30],[31])
) pvt
LEFT JOIN [Users] usr 
     ON usr.Username = pvt.Username
ORDER BY pvt.Username;
```

A test on *rextester* [here](https://rextester.com/MMHFF56333)

Comment: Thx. Btw, I had forgotten to include the usr.Name.  This method has a bit of work to add all 31 days, but they only have to added once to the SQL.

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve this using Pivot, for this you need use CTE to generate Months and Days as you are looking for. I have written the query assuming that your dates falls within one year boundary, if you want to extend to multiple year, you can easily do by generating year between min date and max date.

```
declare @table1 table(Id int, Username varchar(100), IP varchar(20), [Date] datetime)
insert into @table1 select 1, 'murat'   , '192.168.1.100', '2019-02-17 04:12:20.470'
insert into @table1 select 2, 'murat'   , '192.168.1.100', '2019-02-17 04:33:36.120'
insert into @table1 select 3, 'michael', '192.168.120.175', '2019-02-17 08:08:22.210'

declare @table2 table( Username varchar(100), Name varchar(100), Mail varchar(100), Department varchar(100), Record varchar(100), [Function] varchar(100), [Level] int , Manager varchar(100), ManagerTop varchar(100))
insert into @table2 select 'murat', 'Murat', 'murat@asd.com', '11111', 'IT', 'Software Department', 1, 'Kobe', 'Michael'
insert into @table2 select 'michael', 'Michael', 'michael@asd.com', '22222', 'IT', 'Helpdesk', 2, 'Shaq', 'Michael'

;WITH cte(months) 
     AS (SELECT 1 
         UNION ALL 
         SELECT months + 1 
         FROM   cte 
         WHERE  months < 31), 
     n(n) 
     AS (SELECT 1 
         UNION ALL 
         SELECT n + 1 
         FROM   n 
         WHERE  n < 31), 
     cte2 
     AS (SELECT C.months AS CM, 
                n.n      AS CD 
         FROM   cte C 
                CROSS JOIN n), 
     cte3 
     AS (SELECT username, 
                NAME, 
                managertop, 
                mname, 
                t2.[date], 
                C2.cd, 
                CASE 
                  WHEN Month(date) = C2.cm 
                       AND Day(date) = cd THEN 'Yes' 
                  ELSE 'No' 
                END Present, 
                rn 
         FROM   cte2 C2 
                INNER JOIN (SELECT [date], 
                                   T1.username, 
                                   T2.NAME, 
                                   T2.managertop, 
                                   Datename(month, Dateadd(month, Month([date]),0)- 1) 
                                   Mname, 
                                   Row_number() 
                                     OVER ( 
                                       partition BY T1.username 
                                       ORDER BY T1.date) 
                                   RN 
                            FROM   @table1 T1 
                                   INNER JOIN @table2 T2 
                                           ON T1.username = T2.username)T2 
                        ON Month(t2.date) = C2.cm) 
SELECT username, 
       NAME, 
       managertop, 
       mname AS [Month], 
       [1], [2], [3], [4], [5], [6], [7], [8], [9], [10], [11], [12], [13], [14], [15], [16], [17], [18], [19], [20], [21], [22], [23], [24], [25], [26], [27], [28], [29], [30], [31]
FROM   (SELECT * 
        FROM   cte3 
        WHERE  rn = 1) AS SourceTable 
       PIVOT ( Max(present) 
             FOR cd IN ( [1], [2], [3], [4], [5], [6], [7], [8], [9], [10], [11], [12], [13], [14], [15], [16], [17], [18], [19], [20], [21], [22], [23], [24], [25], [26], [27], [28], [29], [30], [31]) ) AS pivottable;
```

[**Online Demo**](https://rextester.com/EFEM35764)

**Output**

```
+----------+---------+------------+----------+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+-----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+
| username | NAME    | managertop | Month    | 1  | 2  | 3  | 4  | 5  | 6  | 7  | 8  | 9  | 10 | 11 | 12 | 13 | 14 | 15 | 16 | 17  | 18 | 19 | 20 | 21 | 22 | 23 | 24 | 25 | 26 | 27 | 28 | 29 | 30 | 31 |
+----------+---------+------------+----------+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+-----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+
| michael  | Michael | Michael    | February | No | No | No | No | No | No | No | No | No | No | No | No | No | No | No | No | Yes | No | No | No | No | No | No | No | No | No | No | No | No | No | No |
+----------+---------+------------+----------+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+-----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+
| murat    | Murat   | Michael    | February | No | No | No | No | No | No | No | No | No | No | No | No | No | No | No | No | Yes | No | No | No | No | No | No | No | No | No | No | No | No | No | No |
+----------+---------+------------+----------+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+-----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+
```